# Is Simple DirectMedia Layer's SDL_GL_GetProcAddress working with OpenGL ES 2.0 for embedded systems

Tags: opengl-es, compatibility, sdl-2

I'm building an application with OpenGL ES 2.0 and SDL2 for Android. Is SDL_GL_GetProcAddress working with OpenGL ES 2.0 on Android? Also i know OpenGL ES 2.0 is a subset of OpenGL, so with this method can it run on desktop systems too?

Comment: ES have some incompatible changes (like `glClearDepthf` instead of `glClearDepth`, or required precision specifiers in shaders). To run it on desktop without modifications your driver needs to support `ARB_ES2_compatibility` extension (which almost every modern driver do).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a quick browse of the SDL repository it should be.

`SDL_video.c` defines the implementation of `SDL_GL_GetProcAddress` simply to check that you've started OpenGL and then to call `_this->GL_GetProcAddress`, where `_this` is a global instance of the video driver.

`SDL_androidvideo.c` sets its `GL_GetProcAddress` to be `Android_GLES_GetProcAddress`, which is a preprocessor substitution for `SDL_EGL_GetProcAddress`.

So, so far: if you call `SDL_GL_GetProcAddress`, you'll get through to `SDL_EGL_GetProcAddress`.

`SDL_egl.c` implements `SDL_EGL_GetProcAddress` but declines to call `eglGetProcAddress` on Android. This looks like it's probably an error — the reason given is [this bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7681) but the status for that bug switched to 'Released' in June 2013, which I believe means that this has been fixed in Android for more than three years.

That aside, the fallback is to use `SDL_LoadFunction`, first with the direct function name, then with it proceeded by an underscore provided it's short enough to fit into the statically-declared buffer. Which this one is.

(so, caveat: `SDL_GL_GetProcAddress` is definitely not thread-safe, even if you've taken appropriate share group steps to use multiple GL contexts, but if you're writing an SDL program you probably don't care)

Android should be using the dlopen version of `SDL_sysloadso` so it looks like `SDL_LoadFunction` is implemented directly as a call to `dlsym`. Which has no issues that I'm aware of under Android.

So, in summary: yes, that call should work. It'll use the platform-specific dynamic library loader rather than the EGL call though it probably doesn't need to, but that's just an implementation detail.